# Using GNU Emacs 24 's TRAMP with plink.exe on Windows 8

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs24, plink, tramp

Being forced to work on Windows, I'm setting up Emacs.

I want to use TRAMP with plink, here is my config :

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/bin")

(require 'tramp)
(set-default 'tramp-auto-save-directory "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp")
(set-default 'tramp-default-method "plink")

(load-theme 'tango-dark t)
```

With plink.exe in `C:\bin`, but when I try to connect I get :

```
M-x /ssh:login@host:
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

So TRAMP doesn't understand it should be using plink ?

Comment: What are you using for a connection string when you `find-file`? If you explicitly include `/ssh:` you are telling Emacs to use SSH. Instead, try using `/plink:`.

Comment: OK That's It ! I feel stupid now... Thank you. A side question: can I use TRAMP (with plink) as a plain ssh client (like the ssh command) ?

Comment: I'm glad that worked. I've added a proper answer below. You should be able to use `plink.exe` from any of Emacs' terminal modes, e.g. `eshell`, `term` or `ansi-term` if you just want to connect over SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a connection string starting with `/ssh:` you are telling TRAMP to use an SSH connection instead of a Plink connection. Using `/plink:` should solve the problem.